# Where does Kaliman come from?

Tags: comics, super-hero

I remember reading [the comic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Elfxm.jpg) but I don't remember his country of origin. The comic itself is obviously Mexican, but I'm fairly certain that he's not Mexican.

I've seen [other data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalim%C3%A1n) that suggests that his origin is not revealed (or that he's an Indian?), but I can't recall anything from the comics that proves or disproves this assertion.

> "Kalimán's true origin is unknown, never revealed in any media, which
>   adds to the sense of mystery that surrounds the character. He's
>   supposedly an Indian orphan found abandoned in a river, and adopted by
>   prince Abul Pasha from one of the kingdoms in the Valley of Kalimanta"

**So where is Kaliman actually from?**

Comment: Thats right besides the ambiguity (I understand that the wiki try to say its a "Mexican character  adventurer" ) I do not remember the origin in universe, the Indian part its right but I never grasped if he was Egyptian , Arabian or what.